# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_transpose_6 to have shape (258, 258, 19) but got array with shape (258, 258, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

model

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, concatenate, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda
```

conv-mpool-conv-mpool-conv-conv-conv-mpool

```
def alexNet(noClass,img_height,img_width,img_channel):
inputs = Input((img_height, img_width, img_channel))
s=inputs
c1 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(s)
c1=BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(c1)

c1 = Conv2D(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c1)
c1=BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(c1)

c1=Conv2D(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c1)
c1=BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1=Conv2D(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c1)
c1=BatchNormalization()(c1)
c1=Conv2D(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c1)
c1=BatchNormalization()(c1)

c1=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(c1)
#decode

c2=UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(c1)

#c2=Conv2DTranspose(256, (3,3),strides=(2,2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c1)#--

c2=Conv2DTranspose(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c2)
c2=BatchNormalization()(c2)
c2=Conv2DTranspose(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c2)
c2=BatchNormalization()(c2)
c2=Conv2DTranspose(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c2)
c2=BatchNormalization()(c2)


c2=UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(c2)

#c2=Conv2DTranspose(256, (3,3),strides=(2,2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c2)#--

c2=Conv2DTranspose(96, (3,3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c2)
c2=BatchNormalization()(c2)

c2=UpSampling2D(size=(2,2))(c2)
c2=BatchNormalization()(c2)
#c2=Conv2DTranspose(96, (3,3),strides=(2,2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal',padding='same')(c2)#--

c2=Conv2DTranspose(96, (3, 3),strides=(1,1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(c2)
c2=BatchNormalization()(c2)
outputs=Conv2DTranspose(noClass, (1, 1), activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='he_normal')(c2)
print(outputs.shape)

print("ghhg")
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.summary()
return model
model=alexNet(noClass=19, img_height=xr, img_width=yr, img_channel=3)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print("sjj")
model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size = 4, verbose=1, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), shuffle=False)
```

The code gives the value error like

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_transpose_6 to have shape (258, 258, 19) but got array with shape (258, 258, 3)

How can fix this?

Comment: Do you have number class of `19`? But your input data has only `3` classes.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I get the predicted image as RGB or have any other way to do that?